# How to fetch data using condition in service file in angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have stored my data in localstorage when user login to the portal using api call,
If data is not found is localstorage, then i have to make a call in service file otherwise i have to get data from localstorage

***service.ts***

```
getOrganisationsList() {
  const organisation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('organisation'));
  if (organisation !== undefined && organisation !== null) {
    console.log('org', this.httpClient.get(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('organisation'))));
    return this.httpClient.get(organisation).map((data: any) => {
      console.log('retrune data');
      return data;
    });
  } else {
    const API_URL = `${this.env.apiUrl}/Organisations`;
    return this.httpClient.get(API_URL).map((data: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('organisation', JSON.stringify(data['Data']['Organisations']));
      return data['Data']['Organisations'];
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
getOwnedOrganisatons() {
  this.orgService.getOrganisationsList().subscribe((resp) => {
    console.log('response', resp);
    this.organisationList = resp;
  });
}
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering?

Comment: If i get data from localstorage, iam getting `response as null` in ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet will work for you. Hope you are using Angular 9 + RxJS 6x.

```js
class MyService {
  getOrganisationsList() {
    const organisation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('organisation'));
    
    // Below condition (with !=) is enough to do undefined & null check.
    if (organisation != null) {
      return of(organisation);
    }
    const API_URL = `${this.env.apiUrl}/Organisations`;
    return this.httpClient.get(API_URL).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('organisation', JSON.stringify(data.Data.Organisations));
        return data.Data.Organisations;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working fine..
And what is the `of` here, i mean how it works

Comment: `of()` converts a value to equivalent observable. You can have a look at manual.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of